# How can I find a section of this formula sample size in which case is not given?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Hey guys so I need your professional help!! I'm working with finding the minimum sample size of an estimate population.

I am given the following problem.

You must find the sample size required to estimate a population proportion
Given: Margin of Error 0.04
Given Confidence Level 95% which is 1.96 Zc
both p^ and q^ are unknown.

I must find n.
I know I have to utilize the following formula

n = ((Zc)^2 * p + q)/E^2

However, I don't know what p and q are how can I find them? I know the E and and Zc but how can I find the rest??

Comment: The variance and standard deviation of a binomial distribution is maximised when $p=1-p=\frac12$

Comment: so p is 1/2

does that make q 1/2 as well?

Comment: Is $q=1-p$ here?

Comment: they had that on an example however I still didnt understand, the solution was

(1.96^2 * .25)/E^2

Comment: sorry I had the wrong equation initially I fixed there, however, the .25 is what I dint understand, the .25 is the product of p and q however it doesn't say how they obtained .25 since they did not give neither p or q to begin with

Comment: Reduces to $ME \approx 1/\sqrt{n}$ for 95% CI. So $n \approx 625$ in the worst case where $p \approx 1/2,$ per @Henry. As long as pop size is at least $10n.$

Comment: In your formula, there is an error. It is not $p+q$. It must be $\hat{p}\hat{q}$, assuming $\hat{q}=1-\hat{p}$. I think it comes out to be $approx\;\;600$, on using $\hat{p}=0.5$.

Comment: I suggest that the title must be modified.